# How to assign data frame column by it's string in R?

Tags: r, string, dataframe, assign

Let's say I have three `.csv` files with this format:

```
Date        Value_1   Value_2
2015/01/01  0         9
2015/01/02  1         1
2015/01/03  2         7
2015/01/04  2         8
2015/01/05  4         6
```

I want to assign new column. I'm was trying this code:

```
Str <- c("A","B","C")

for (i in 1:3){
  assign(Str[i], read.csv(paste(Str[i], "_data.csv", sep=""), header=""))
  assign(paste(Str[i], "$Value_3", sep=""), c(1,2,3,4,5))
}
```

But this code is just creating a new variable:

```
assign(paste(Str[i], "$Value_3", sep=""), c(1,2,3,4,5))
```

What can I do to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

One option would be using `fread`

```
library(data.table)
files <- list.files("path/to/folder", "^[ABC]_data\\.csv$", full.names = TRUE)
lst <- lapply(files, function(x) fread(x)[, Value_3 := 1:5])
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
variable.name[,"Value_3"] <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
```

instead of the dollar notation